# How to read YAML / use "yaml-cpp" with C++Builder?

Tags: c++, makefile, c++builder, yaml-cpp

I am using Embarcadero C++Builder v10.4 with a C++ VCL application.

I need to read YAML, and the most referenced API is "yaml-cpp".

What I am asking for is help or guidance on what I have to do to be able to use yaml-cpp.

So far, I have been able to solve my tasks by integrating headers and also DLLs. For the integration of the API, I feel there is a lack of knowledge that that I need to fill.

How do I create the Makefiles correctly for Embarcadero? What should I get after `make`, and how do I tie it in?

What I tried so far:

I tried to build it like it is described on GitHub and create some Borland Makefiles.

I believe I have to `make` the build, but I get an error after 2%. I read [Using CMake with C++ Builder](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_CMake_with_C%2B%2B_Builder) and created the makefiles with the example in the end of "Building using CMake". But I get an error after 94% when trying to make.

I have the feeling that I am doing something generally wrong.

I am very grateful for any help.

Last Error CMake with Rad Studio console:

```
C:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master\build>cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=bcc32x.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=bcc32x.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE_INIT=Release -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON -G "Borland Makefiles" ..

-- The CXX compiler identification is Embarcadero 7.50.37590
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Studio/21.0/bin/bcc32x.exe - skipped
-- Configuring done (2.0s)
-- Generating done (0.3s)
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_C_COMPILER


-- Build files have been written to: C:/git/Temp/yaml-cpp-master/build

C:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master\build>make
MAKE Version 5.43  Copyright (c) 1987, 2019 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -P C:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master\build\CMakeFiles\VerifyGlobs.cmake
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -SC:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master -BC:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master\build --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master\build\CMakeFiles C:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master\build\\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
        make  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 -l -o  all
MAKE Version 5.43  Copyright (c) 1987, 2019 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
        make  -f CMakeFiles\yaml-cpp.dir\build.make -l -o  CMakeFiles\yaml-cpp.dir\depend
MAKE Version 5.43  Copyright (c) 1987, 2019 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "Borland Makefiles" C:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master C:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master C:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master\build C:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master\build C:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master\build\CMakeFiles\yaml-cpp.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
        make  -f CMakeFiles\yaml-cpp.dir\build.make -l -o  CMakeFiles\yaml-cpp.dir\build
MAKE Version 5.43  Copyright (c) 1987, 2019 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/yaml-cpp.dir/src/contrib/graphbuilder.cpp.obj
        C:\PROGRA~2\EMBARC~1\Studio\21.0\bin\bcc32x.exe -DYAML_CPP_STATIC_DEFINE @CMakeFiles/yaml-cpp.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Weffc++ -Wno-long-long -pedantic -pedantic-errors -oCMakeFiles\yaml-cpp.dir\src\contrib\graphbuilder.cpp.obj -P -c C:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master\src\contrib\graphbuilder.cpp
Embarcadero C++ 7.50 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2021 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.

....

[ 94%] Linking CXX executable parse.exe
        cd C:\git\Temp\yaml-cpp-master\build\util
        C:\PROGRA~2\EMBARC~1\Studio\21.0\bin\bcc32x.exe --rsp-quoting=windows -oparse.exe @MAKE0000.@@@
Embarcadero C++ 7.50 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2021 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
bcc32x.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nobuiltininc' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Turbo Incremental Link 6.95 Copyright (c) 1997-2021 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Error: Nicht aufl÷sbares externes '__Atomic_fetch_add_4' referenziert von C:\GIT\TEMP\YAML-CPP-MASTER\BUILD\YAML-CPP.LIB|nodebuilder.cpp
Error: Linken kann nicht ausgef³hrt werden
bcc32x.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 2 (use -Xdriver -v to see invocation)

** error 2 ** deleting util\parse.exe

** error 1 ** deleting util\CMakeFiles\yaml-cpp-parse.dir\all

** error 1 ** deleting all
```

Comment: Without error messages we cannot help you. Those percentages mean nothing. Show the full command and output/error log from invoking CMake and make

Comment: The link error you get seems to be because `std::atomic` is used. Does bcc32x expect an extra library somewhere?

Comment: I would love to answer this question, but i have no clue at all. :(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a Q&A site. Please take the [tour] and read the [help], especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Asking for tutorials is off-topic. What is your **specific** technical question?

Comment: Specific question is: What do i do wrong by creating the Makefiles or with make.
If this is not specific enough you can close this topic because my knowlegde is not deep enough to give you information about extra libraries. It is the embacadero c++ builder on which i did no modifications. And i would love to know how to make it work.